# Vimeo player.play() not starting player

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-player

Vimeo method play() doesnt work and player object is undefined when I try to log it from console.

I am initializing vimeo player on my page like this:

```
<div id="myVideo"></div>    

var options = {
    url: "https://vimeo.com/showcase/xxxxxxx",
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    autoplay: true,
    autopause: false,
    loop: true,
    muted: true,
    background: 1
};

var videoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('myVideo', options);
```

then I am doing console log in my code

```
  $(document).ready(
  function(){  
    console.log(videoPlayer);
    videoPlayer.play(); 
 });
```

**console.log(videoPlayer)** works just fine here and prints object, but **videoPlayer.play()**; does nothing. When I am trying to do console.log(videoPlayer) from browser console I got **Uncaught ReferenceError: videoPlayer is not defined**. I am trying to start video directly from JS because autoplay doesnt work at all.

Player is initializing fine, but I have to press play button to start the video, but I need it to start automatically.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? The `play` method works just fine for me: https://codepen.io/JokerNN/pen/MWWyPBY . Also be sure that autoplay is enabled by user. Otherwise browser will just block the auto play

Comment: [This one is also related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use). Chrome will block the video if user didn't interact with the document first

Comment: Well, thats all my code that relates to the video player. Is that possible that problem is with using showcase instead of just single video? However, as I said Player initializes fine, i can see whole playlist.

Comment: For player.js, you will need to provide a single video @ИгорьБыстревский

Comment: What do I do if I need a lot of videos to be played as playlist? Create new player object for every single video? @frobinsonj

Comment: Instead, take a look at [embedding showcases](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/showcases#embedding-a-showcase-step-2)

Comment: I'm afraid they don't support APIs like `play` for showcases: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/issues/457

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vimeo javascript api player.play() not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001654/vimeo-javascript-api-player-play-not-playing)

Comment: There was no answer that would help me. Also in my question I am facing the problem that I cant access player object from browser console after page is loaded @weegee

Answer (score 0):

Try to init you variable inside document.ready function:

```
  $(document).ready(
  function(){  
    var videoPlayer = new Vimeo.Player('myVideo', options);
    videoPlayer.play(); 
 });
```

Comment: What is your result when you try: document.getElementById('myVideo')

Comment: It returns **<div id="myVideo"></div>** in console

Answer (score 0):

Well, after all I just ended up using single videos and switching them through js. Show cases does not support many of features that can be used with single videos.  I still cant access player object from console. But at least play() method is working now, since I am initializing it with video id instead of url

```
  var options = {
    id: xxxxxxxxx,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    muted: true,
};
```

Comment: Can you share the JavaScript code for switching between single videos?